# Why do dynamic images I uploaded using Django admin on a Heroku deployment not showing up?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-admin

I have an e-commerce Django website hosted in Heroku (free acc). I dynamically upload the image and price through the Django admin page. The images were showing up for one day, but from the next day, I am getting an "image not found (404)" error. What's the reason for this error?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

You can't save (persistantly) media files into Heroku's local filesystem.

> The Heroku filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
> container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a
> process known as ["Cycling"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).
>
> These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for
> persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we
> recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a
> dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). If
> you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we
> also have addons here that handle storage and processing of static
> assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Reference: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted